# Помогите найти ошибку: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android, java

Код http://pastebin.com/x20dq8px

```
package com.example.Test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        String httpsURL = "http://bysay.ru/test";
        String query = null;
        try {
            query = "test="+ URLEncoder.encode("2", "UTF-8");
            URL myurl = new URL(httpsURL);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)myurl.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
            output.writeBytes(query);
            output.close();
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Главное, этот код работает в JAVA, но не в ANDROID. Почему?

Comment: паста не найдена по ссылке

Comment: Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException    
что переводится как ОперацииССетьюВГлавномПотоке    
что запрещено.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Начиная с Android 3.0 нельзя выполнять веб-запросы в основном потоке. Используйте [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).